Why can’t I upload a photo to a previous question?
When I click the photo icon to add a photo as you described the green button to post it is greyed out.
Please tell me as well where to ask your help without writing a new post like this?

Photo icon > browse (to upload from your device) / paste (to paste any url) > Add picture > Post (or save edits, whichever it will be).... note that the photo must be less than 2 MB

Reply or ask for further help under your original question as a comment beneath it

The green button is greyed out because you have not yet set an image (this may be bad UI design?)   Above the greyed out "Add Picture" button, there are links for Brows, drag-and-drop or paste an image link - any one of those should work - and then the add picture button should illuminate and allow you to add it to your post.

I just tried a direct Cut & Paste of a screenshot into your question. Can you try that?

Does this answer your question? How to post images here

It’s not entirely clear what exactly is your question, but I think we can resolve this nevertheless:

If you have questions about the site’s mechanics, use the corresponding Meta - where this got moved to.
If you want to reply to a comment under your own post, you can do so as needed. There’s a catch though: If you use an unregistered account, the system will recognize you only up to a certain point. One of the reasons why registering is helpful. If you want, you can request both accounts to be merged, see the help. If you want to comment elsewhere, you need to gain the required reputation (aka points) for the privilege.
And finally, if you struggle with the upload because the button is grey, you need to select an image first, as mentioned in the comment.

